# overflow:scroll isn't working for php comment system

Tags: php, html, css

trying to make my comments box scrollable using overflow:scroll. at first I thought it wasn't working cause I was using max-height over just height but even with a fixed height the scroll bar does not appear and the comments push their 400px boundary.

Here is the code of the comments box.

```
<?php
$act = $_POST['act'];
if($act == "post") {
$name = $_POST['name'];
$message  = $_POST ['message'];
@$fp = fopen("comments/comments.php", 'a');
if (!$fp) {
    //The file could not be opened
    echo "There was an error! Please try again later!";
    exit;
} else {
    //The file was successfully opened, lets write the comment to it.
    $outputstring = 
    "<article class='comment'>
    <br>
    <p><span class='label'>Name:</span> " .$name. "</p>
    <br> 
    <p><span class='label'>Comment:</span>" .$message. "</p>
    <br>
    <hr/ >
    </article>";

    //Write to the file
    fwrite($fp, $outputstring, strlen($outputstring));

    //We are finished writing, close the file for security / memory management purposes
    fclose($fp);

    //Post the success message
    echo "Your post was successfully entered. Click <a href='index.php'>here</a> to continue.";
}
} else {
//We are not trying to post a comment, show the form.
?>

//THIS HERE IS THE COMMENTS SECTION DIV

<div class="commentSection">
<h3>comments:</h3>
<hr/>
<?php include("comments/comments.php"); ?>
</div>

//THIS HERE IS THE COMMENTS SECTION DIV


<br><br>

<h3>Post a comment:</h3>
<form action="index.php" method="post">
<label>Name:<label>
<input type="text" name="name" value=""></input>
<br/>
<label>Comment:</label>
<textarea name="message"></textarea>
<input type="hidden" name="act" value="post"></input>
<br/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></input>
</form>
<?php
}
?>
```

and here is the css style for it.

```
.commentSection{
height:400px;
overflow:scroll;
}
```

anyone got any ideas to why it won't do it? is it because im populating the div with php or something?

thanks in advance.

Comment: PHP does nothing to do for the layout. Can you create a demo with your rendered HTML and Css?

Comment: testing-grounds.webege.com is the site the comments are one. no criticism please its just a mess around site for me to learn :P

Comment: Looks fine for me, are you sure your browser isn't caching the old CSS file?

Comment: just cleared cache on ie and chrome and re opened again, still no scroll bar, none in dw preview either or aptana preview.

Comment: You fail to understand my point, its the HTML and CSS that affect the layout. I am trying to teach you some basic things too.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you starx, you asked for a demo and I gave you the site that I implemented it on? sorry for the confusion.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Ca8ZB/ there is a jsfiddle with just the html output from the site I linked which I grabbed from the view source, styled it with the overflow and height and it works, which is why I was thinking it was the php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following line doesn't have a closing `}`

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
```

which is likely its not appearing how it should, because in chrome i checked the css file and it was there but in the properties of the div it didn't show the `height:400px; overflow:scroll;` but when I added a `}` it worked. Most likely it sees that there is missing a `}` and most browsers try to guess where the missing info goes and it places it at the end of the file/last line (you won't see this in the view source or what not but its done internally) also the browser's window isn't 600px max/screen.

Comment: You, are a champion. when I added the .commentSection styles I deleted that } thinking it was just a mistake, I really should clean my code up.

everything is working now thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

If the HTML inside of the comments.php file is invalid it will break your containing DIV thereby breaking the code and preventing the intended style.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Ca8ZB/ when I grab the plain html from the source code and style it, it works fine. I don't understand?